# Is the Android Manifest a resource file?

Tags: android

Is the Android Manifest file technically considered a resource file since you are able to add information regarding an application such as activity title, icon, etc?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. They separate "App Manifest" from "App Resources" in the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I think it's kinda between a build/configuration file and a resource file. it's just my opinion though. Any reason why you need to know the type of file it's classed into (writing a paper, etc)?

Comment: I am just curious about the actual categorization of this file since it kind of seems like it could be either one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't so. The resource files are normally located inside a folder called "res" and android manifest is outside of that folder.